# Set opacity of background map with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

With `ggmap` and `ggplot` and the following code... (non-reproducible, but imho not necessary to understand the problem).

```
map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 10.64, lat = 50.56), maptype = "terrain", source = "google", zoom = 6, language = "de-DE", color = "bw")

ggmap(map) + 
  geom_point(data = frage_3_daten, aes(x = lng_google, y = lat_google, colour = pronunciation_id), alpha = 0.2) + 
  scale_colour_hue(name = "Aussprache", labels = c("Krampus", "Grittibänz")) +
  ggtitle("Gebäck in Form einer menschlichen Gestalt") +
  xlab("Länge") + ylab("Breite") +
  theme_srf()
```

I can produce this beautiful point map on top of the German-speaking Europe.

[image]

**Now**: My only (and hopefully simple) question is: How can I lower the opacity of the background layer, so that the points become more important?

I managed the following "hack" by setting the `darken` parameter: `ggmap(map, darken = c(0.6, "white"))`.

[image]

This almost solves my problem, but maybe there's actually a (hidden) option to globally lower the opacity of the first, map layer (or more generally, of any layer in a plot).

Comment: You can add custom styles to the map... `ggmap(get_googlemap("chicago", style=style_string))` see `?get_googlemap` for docs

Comment: Is the title a joke, or does this map really show the distribution of humanoid baked goods in Central Europe?

Comment: Almost - it shows their pronunciation! Red is "Krampus", blue is "Grittibänz", and that's how they look like: https://www.google.ch/search?q=grittib%C3%A4nz&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&imgil=upLFGQTVztW0iM%253A%253BLrw25-M5weA7gM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fhohenauer.info%25252Fgrittibaenz%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=upLFGQTVztW0iM%253A%252CLrw25-M5weA7gM%252C_&usg=__Q-k6r96hUVw7hvd1VZiTd1SEeIA%3D&biw=1680&bih=890&ved=0ahUKEwjRnOvjnO3RAhWJoRQKHcKqDv4QyjcIRQ&ei=0_OQWJHnEYnDUsLVuvAP#imgrc=upLFGQTVztW0iM%3A

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to adjust the `darken` parameter, and you don't want to do a deep dive into custom styles for the Google Map, you can modify the `ggmap` object directly.

The `ggmap` is essentially a character matrix, where each cell is a hex code for the color to be reproduced there. (There are some extra attributes that describe the longitude and latitude (in the EPSG:4326 coordinate reference system) of the lower left and upper right points of the `ggmap`, as well as the source and zoom level.)

You can use the `adjustcolor()` function from base `R` to take a color (as a hex code, an integer, or a character string-- anything that the `col2rgb()` function will accept) and dial up or down the red, green, blue, and alpha channels. The alpha channel controls the transparency, where 1 is fully opaque and 0 is fully transparent.

Here's a reproducible example...

First, get the `meuse` data, which comes with the `sp` package.

```
data(meuse)
```

Transform the dataframe into an `sp` object, assign it's proper coordinate reference system (which I found [here](https://edzer.github.io/sp/)), then transform it's coordinate reference system to longitude/latitude.

```
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- "+init=epsg:28992 +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,-0.398957388243134,0.343987817378283,-1.87740163998045,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs"
meuse <- spTransform(meuse, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

Get the Google base map using the approximate center of all the points. I use the same other arguments that you do, but set the zoom much higher since these points are all quite close to each other.

```
meuse_basemap <- get_map(location = colMeans(coordinates(meuse)), 
                         maptype = "terrain", 
                         source = "google", 
                         zoom = 13, 
                         language = "de-DE", 
                         color = "bw")
```

Here's where I modify the `ggmap` to make it transparent. I save the attributes as an object so that I can reassign the same attributes to the more transparent `ggmap`. I couldn't find a way to modify just the values of the `ggmap` in place without stripping the `ggmap` attributes (which then means the modified `ggmap` doesn't work with the `ggmap()` function).

```
meuse_basemap_attributes <- attributes(meuse_basemap)
```

Create a matrix the same dimensions as the Google basemap, but with all the color hex codes in each cell adjusted to half the transparency.

```
meuse_basemap_transparent <- matrix(adjustcolor(meuse_basemap, 
                                                alpha.f = 0.5), 
                                    nrow = nrow(meuse_basemap))
```

Assign the saved attributes to the modified matrix to turn it back into a usable `ggmap`.

```
attributes(meuse_basemap_transparent) <- meuse_basemap_attributes
```

Here's the original plot:

```
ggmap(meuse_basemap) +
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(meuse), 
             aes(x = x, y = y, color = dist), 
             cex = 2)
```

[image: original ggmap]

And here's the more transparent one!

```
ggmap(meuse_basemap_transparent) +
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(meuse), 
             aes(x = x, y = y, color = dist), 
             cex = 2)
```

[image: more transparent ggmap]